# load different images for each item on the listbox

Tags: javascript, listbox

Javascript:

```
     function changeMap()
    {
       imagesource =  "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=500x500&maptype=hybrid&zoom=16&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:K|28.541250,77.204100" ;
       mapimage.src  = imagesource ;
    }
```

Html code :

```
         <select name="choose_colony" id="choose_colony" size="8" onchange="changeMap()" style="float: left;">
        <option value="1" >Big apartments</option> 
        .
        .
        <option value="999">plaza</option>
        </select>
        <img name="mapimage" src="" alt="Select your Colony" style="float: right;">
```

In this whenever a selection on the listbox is made changeMap is called and an image is loaded. What I want is for a different image to be loaded everytime depending upon the option selected .

there will be over 2000 entries in the listbox. Considering this what is the best way of going about this ? I can figure out the if/then part , but my main question is whether its ok to put all the 2000 long image addresses in the html file itself ? 
I hope I was clear ..

Comment: 9 questions and not a single accepted answer...Too bad...

Comment: sorry about that . I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to go, which one is best depends on your setup:

1. Have the addresses at the clientside
   (either in the html, or better: in a
   separate .js file using the JSON
   format).
2. Have the addresses at serverside,
   and use AJAX to ask the address when
   the selectbox changes.

The first one is

- fastest for your user, once the page and .js file has loaded
- requires one big transfer from the server
- best used in a scenario where bandwith is cheaper than roundtriptime, or when the user is likely to be scrolling through the selectbox, demanding multiple images per visit (the .js file will be cached on further visits)

The second scenario is

- A bit slower for the user, each time he changes the selectbox, he has to wait for a trip to the server
- Requires more but shorter transfers from the server
- best used in a scenario where a user only visit the page a few times, and only makes a few selects.

Comment: thanks. I think I'll go with the second option . Also for option 1 what would be the download size of .js file if there are 2000 entries ?

Comment: Probably about 200kb, but if you send this over a compressed line (gzip/decode) and since this is just one download, this could be fine. An small image is easily around the same size, and those are used about everywhere. Honestly, I would go with approach 1 at first myself :)